# Hardware information returned by WMI changes unexpectedly

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, wmic

I have been using WMI to query some hardware information. The following PowerShell script lists all the information I acquired and they are mixed together and encrypted to generate a short string. We noticed the string was changed today and none of either CPU, BIOS and motherboard have been changed.

```
function Output-WMI
{
  param([String]$path, [String]$prop)
  "{0,15} - {1,-18}: {2}" -f $path, $prop, (wmic path $path get $prop)[2].Trim()
}

Output-WMI "Win32_Processor" "UniqueId"
Output-WMI "Win32_Processor" "ProcessorId"
Output-WMI "Win32_Processor" "Name"
Output-WMI "Win32_Processor" "Manufacturer"
Output-WMI "Win32_Processor" "MaxClockSpeed"

Output-WMI "Win32_BIOS" "Manufacturer"
Output-WMI "Win32_BIOS" "SMBIOSBIOSVersion"
Output-WMI "Win32_BIOS" "IdentificationCode"
Output-WMI "Win32_BIOS" "SerialNumber"
Output-WMI "Win32_BIOS" "ReleaseDate"
Output-WMI "Win32_BIOS" "Version"

Output-WMI "Win32_BaseBoard" "Model"
Output-WMI "Win32_BaseBoard" "Manufacturer"
Output-WMI "Win32_BaseBoard" "Name"
Output-WMI "Win32_BaseBoard" "SerialNumber"
```

Does anyone know how these hardware information could be changed?

We have known that there is no update installed. We know that today, Win32_BaseBoard class returns no instance (return message is 'No Instance(s) Available').

Comment: No idea. My first steps would probably be checking the eventlogs and group policies. I would also double-check the installed updates. As a side note: why are you using `wmic` instead of `Get-WmiObject` when you're already using PowerShell anyway? Side note #2: this isn't really a programming issue, so you may want to post questions like this on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) in the future.

Comment: Note #1: This is just an demonstration of what we have collected from WMI. I believe ```wmic``` and ```Get-WmiObject``` return the same thing. Note #2: You are right. I will do that in the future. Thanks!